# apache2 redirecting external Ip to internal Ip

Tags: apache-2.4, port-forwarding, pfsense, ubuntu-16.04

I have an apache2 server running behind a pfsense firewall. I created a port-forwarding rule to redirect port 8000 to port 80 on an ubuntu hosting the apache2 instance.

My problem is the following : when I use my external ip on my browser, I can access my server but when I try to access a subfolder, I'm redirected to the local Ip. Which give me a timeout since I'm not on the same network.

My "virtual host" config is the following :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost:80
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    UseCanonicalName Off 
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

I didn't find any redirection rules on any config file (since the rest is default apache2 config).

Comment: servername localhost - this needs to be the fully qualified domain name ServerName host.example.com

Comment: hum then what if I don't have one ... should I just comment this line ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hum finally found where was the problem : subfolder was a prestashop app there was a config field in `Url & SEO` set to my local Ip.